# mySQL: utf8 charset on index table and duplicate key error

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I have expected a strange behavior of mySQL when using a varchar field encoded in utf8 as primary key. It fails with duplicate key error for strings which aren't equal in my development environment.

A short example:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';

CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`) VALUES ('das'), ('daß');
```

Fails with error: `Duplicate entry 'daß' for key 'PRIMARY'.`

I am running mySQL 5.5.35 on ubuntu 13.10 with default configuration.

On another mySQL Server (version 5.0.95) the same queries did not fail. Is this because of mySQL version or is there a configuration option to set encoding of index tables?

I run into this issue while trying to import a mySQL dump from productive server into my development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the collation `utf8_unicode_ci` when you use German characters, according to the discussion in this bug: [Bug #39816 German collation under utf8_unicode_ci is incorrect](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39816).

Despite the title of that bug, I just tested this on 5.6.15, and your test case works, whereas the default unicode collation does not work:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`) VALUES ('das'), ('daß');
```

PS: I recommend that you use a development environment the same versions of all software as your production environment, or at least share the same major version. You're bound to run into other incompatibilities if you develop in 5.5 and then try to deploy to 5.0.

Comment: Yeah, that's working. But I am still confused why dump with phpmyadmin fails to import. Is phpmyadmin missing the DEFAULT COLLATE on export or is mysql 5.0.x handling this problem different or is there a global setting for DEFAULT COLLATE which is different between my two mysql servers?

Comment: You can try `SHOW CREATE DATABASE <databasename>` on both servers, so you can compare their default charset and collation.

Comment: I found out that I could get collation for field with `SHOW FULL COLUMNS <tablename>`. On both servers collation is `utf_general_ci`. Still having no idea what is causing the different behavior. But I think I will stop investigation here as I know how to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that the database didnt reconize `daß` it reconized as `das` and then it becomes double entry for id, while this is just a test table

why not create column id with autoincrenebt and other column name where you have those values Like that:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 `name` varchar(5)
 ) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

 INSERT INTO `test` (`name`) VALUES ('das'), ('daß');
```

[**WATCH DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1dbc9/1)

---

> Your question was a bug discussed [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28162) with german charcters.

Answer (score 0):

`utf8_general_mysql500_ci` and `utf8_general_ci` differ in whether `ß` is treated as equal to `s` or not.

To 'fix' the incompatibility, the collation utf8_general_mysql500_ci was added in MySQL 5.1.62 / 5.5.21 / 5.6.5.

More history:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#german_sharp_s_