# Duplicate entry when inserting utf-8 data to primary key

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I am getting Duplicate entry error when trying to insert utf-8 data to primary key on MySql

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `UserName` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserName`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4   
COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Insert:

```
insert test(`UserName`) VALUES('büsra'), ('büşra');
```

Result:

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'büşra' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I think the SQL Server is configured correctly:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';

character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    utf8mb4
character_set_system    utf8
collation_connection    utf8_general_ci
collation_database  utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_server    utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I have tries to find a solution in: [mySQL: utf8 charset on index table and duplicate key error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969927/mysql-utf8-charset-on-index-table-and-duplicate-key-error)
but could not find any.

What am i doing wrong?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The *collation* you have chosen regards those characters as equal in a comparison…

Comment: @deceze Which collation should I use? is there an easy way to test collation with data?

Comment: *"The collation you have chosen regards those characters as equal in a comparison"* @deceze not t100%  topic but MySQL under version 8.0 is a bit wierd also with NULL bytes in some collations when detecting duplicates consider [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eDxZLH2C1sSznU5iQUcsLq/1) .. This seams to be fixed in MySQL 8 as you get a expected Duplicate entry error.

Comment: Where are there NUL bytes?  That should not happen in UTF-8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Thanks for whittling down the problem to a very simple test case.)

utf8mb4_unicode_ci does case folding and accent stripping.  Hence, `ş` = `s`.

utf8mb4_bin would treat them as different.  But even `A` and `a` would be different.

utf8mb4_turkish_ci or utf8mb4_romanian_ci may be what you want?  They treat `ş` as a separate letter, falling between `sz` and `ta`.  More details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html

Also turkish_ci, but not romanian_ci, treats `ü` as a separate letter.

Comment: @Erez Ben Harush - In case you are focused on Turkish, I added to my answer.